# after woocomrce 3.0 update featured product using custom query are not showing properly

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

this is my code.

```
  <?php
 $meta_query[] = array(
  'key'   => '_featured',
  'value' => 'yes'
  );
  $args = array(
  'post_type'   =>  'product',
    'stock'       =>  1,
  'showposts'   =>  12,
   'orderby'     =>  'date',
   'order'       =>  'DESC',
   'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query
 );



?>
```

This was working perfect before woocommerce 3.0 update but after that this not shows the correct products.

Comment: WooCommerce 3.0+ is still full of bugs and it's a Mega Major version… I s better to wait some time before updating a production website

Comment: And certainly should be tested on a staging site first.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'stock'       =>  1,
    'showposts'   =>  12,
    'orderby'     =>  'date',
    'order'       =>  'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_featured',
            'value' => 'yes'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved a bug related to this. Try the following code :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'stock'       =>  1,
    'showposts'   =>  12,
    'orderby'     =>  'date',
    'order'       =>  'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);
```